# Calculate $\Delta \phi$ in distributional, $\phi (x) := -{1 \over {2 \pi}} \ln |x| $ sense for every $x \in R^2$ \ $ \{0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $\phi (x):= -{1 \over {2 \pi}} \ln |x| $ for every $x \in D: R^2$ \ $ \{0\}$. 
Calculate $\Delta \phi$ in the distributional sense.

From general theory, I know that , having a $\psi \in C_c^{\infty} (E)$, we have: $\langle \Delta T_\phi , \psi\rangle=-\langle \nabla T_\phi ,\nabla \psi\rangle=\langle T_\phi ,\Delta\psi\rangle$.

Here I can identify $T_\phi = \phi(x)$ and so $(T_\phi)' = \phi(x)'$ and $(T_\phi)'' = \phi(x)''$ .

But in this way, applying the standard definition of distributional derivative I have: $\langle \Delta T_\phi , \psi\rangle = \int_D \Delta(-{1 \over {2 \pi}} \ln |x|)\psi dx dx =  \int_D  ({1 \over {2 \pi x^2}} )\psi dx dx = \int_D  (-{1 \over {2 \pi}} \ln |x|) \Delta \psi dx dx $ for the general property of distribution.

But I can't identify $\Delta \phi(x)$ better that $\phi''$ here. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by $\phi'$ and $\phi''$, since the function is defined on $R^2\setminus\{0\}$. I imagine you mean the gradient and the hessian of it. I think that the main problem is that you clearly have a singularity in $0$, and so the integration by parts formula you gave before contains also a boundary term (the $0$, or an $\epsilon$ neighbourhood of it that you shrink to zero at the end of your computations) which in fact realise the magic property of the fundamental solution of the Laplacian..

Comment: $\phi$ is $L^1_{loc}$ and smooth away from $0$ and $\Delta \phi = O(1/(x^2+y^2))$ thus let $\psi \in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}), \psi(x)=1$ on $[-1,1]$ then $<\Delta \phi, \varphi>= <\Delta \phi, \varphi-(\varphi(0)+x(\partial_x\varphi)(0)+y (\partial_y\varphi)(0)> + \varphi(0)A+(\partial_x\varphi)(0)B+(\partial_y\varphi)(0)C$ where the RHS is given by the obvious integrals on $\Bbb{R}^2-0$ and $A = <\phi,\Delta \psi>, B=<\phi,\Delta (x\psi)>, C=<\phi,\Delta (y\psi)>$.

Comment: @Duca_Conte you talk about harmonic functions and Laplacian property about that?

Comment: Yes, it was just a suggestion . In the classical computation of the fundamental solution of the Laplacian (without thinking about distributions for the moment), the point is that $u=\phi*f$ solves $-\Delta u = f$. This can be proved removing the singularity in zero with an $\epsilon$ ball, and integrating by parts many times. Rewriting it in the distributional sense $-\Delta\phi(x)=\delta_x$. It is important to keep in mind the boundary term.

Answer (score 1):

Set $u = \ln |x|,$ and take some $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2).$ Then, $\langle \Delta u, \varphi \rangle = \langle u, \Delta \varphi \rangle$. Now note that $u \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ so we have 
$$\langle u, \Delta \varphi\rangle = \iint \ln|x| \, \Delta\varphi(x) \, dx = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \iint_{|x|>\epsilon} \ln|x| \, \Delta\varphi(x) \, dx.$$

Using integration by parts and using polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ we get
$$
\iint_{|x|>\epsilon} \ln|x| \, \Delta\varphi(x) \, dx
= \int_{|x|=\epsilon} \ln|x| \, \nabla\varphi(x) \cdot \hat{r} \, ds
- \iint_{|x|>\epsilon} \nabla\ln|x| \cdot \nabla\varphi(x) \, dx
\\
= \int_{|x|=\epsilon} \ln|x| \, \nabla\varphi(x) \cdot \hat{r} \, ds
- \iint_{|x|>\epsilon} \hat{r}r^{-1} \cdot (\hat{r}\partial_r+\hat{\theta}r^{-1}\partial_\theta)\varphi(x) \, r \, dr \, d\theta
\\
= \int_{|x|=\epsilon} \ln\epsilon \, \partial_r\varphi(x) \, \epsilon\,d\theta
- \iint_{|x|>\epsilon} \partial_r\varphi(r,\theta) \, dr \, d\theta
.
$$

The first integral vanishes as $\epsilon \to 0$ and the second integral becomes
$$
\iint_{|x|>\epsilon} \partial_r\varphi(r,\theta) \, dr \, d\theta
= \int_0^{2\pi} \left( \int_\epsilon^\infty \partial_r\varphi(r,\theta) \, dr \right) \, d\theta
\\
= \int_0^{2\pi} \left( -\varphi(\epsilon,\theta) \right) \, d\theta
\to \int_0^{2\pi} \left( -\varphi(0,\theta) \right) \, d\theta
\\
= -2\pi \, \varphi(0)
= \langle -2\pi\delta, \varphi \rangle
.
$$

Thus, $\Delta u = -2\pi \, \delta.$

Comment: What do your mean by "integration by part"? Green's formula?

Comment: @Jethro. Yes, more precisely the two-dimensional divergence theorem: 

Since $\nabla \cdot (f \, \nabla g) = \nabla f \cdot \nabla g + f \, \nabla\cdot\nabla g$ we have
$$\iint_\Omega f \, \nabla\cdot\nabla g \, dx = \iint_\Omega \nabla\cdot(f \, \nabla g) \, dx - \iint_\Omega \nabla f\cdot\nabla g \, dx$$
where the first integral on the right hand side can be converted to a boundary integral by the divergence theorem:
$$\iint_\Omega \nabla\cdot(f \, \nabla g) \, dx = \int_{\partial\Omega} f \, \nabla g \cdot n \, ds.$$